# Adding SSH site in Jenkins throws exception

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins 2.89.2 installed as Windows Service. When I tried to add SSH Site under configuration, I get an exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.CredentialsSSHSite.<init>(CredentialsSSHSite.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.invokeConstructor(RequestImpl.java:529)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:783)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.access$200(RequestImpl.java:83)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:678)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:478)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:474)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSONToList(RequestImpl.java:519)
at org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SSHBuildWrapper$DescriptorImpl.configure(SSHBuildWrapper.java:193)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.configureDescriptor(Jenkins.java:3706)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doConfigSubmit(Jenkins.java:3670)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(Unknown Source)
```

Anyone else experienced this error?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known, but not yet fixed bug [JENKINS-46172](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46172) 
I've experienced this error when because of errors on page had left unspecified ssh credentials.
[image]

In my case "Credentials" list was empty and "Add" button didn't work.
So I had to go to "Jenkins/Credentials" menu and enter credentials there.
It made possible to select credentials from list and ssh host addition went without described error.